# Casting to reference in a template seems to cast away const-ness

Tags: c++

Consider the following C++ code:

```
typedef std::string& mutable_string_ref;
const std::string str = "abc";
mutable_string_ref ref(str);
```

This obviously results in a compiler error, because you cannot create a mutable reference to a const string.  With GCC 4.7.2, the error this produces is:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘mutable_string_ref {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’
```

**BUT**... why is it that if we try the same thing, only we pass the reference type as a *template parameter*, suddenly it seems to ignore the const-ness?

Consider:

```
template <class T>
T get()
{
    const static std::string s = "abc";
    return T(s);
}

int main()
{
    std::string& s = get<std::string&>();
    s = "blah"; // undefined behavior!!
}
```

The above code compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2, with no warnings.  I don't understand why it compiles.  It seems the expression `T(s)` is basically being interpreted as a C-style cast that just casts away const-ness.  But why?  I instantiated the function template `get` with `T = std::string&`, so the expression `return T(s)` should fail to compile because `s` is `const`.  Yet it doesn't fail.

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/TAO5C6

Is this a compiler bug?  Or is there some valid reason this compiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing, you're C-style casting, which indeed has the ability to cast away constness.

From the standard:

> #### 5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]
>
> ***1** A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4).*
>
> #### 5.4 Explicit type conversion (cast notation)
>
> ***1** The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. [...]*

Comment: Wow, that is tricky... so to respect the const-ness I'd have to do something like `return T(static_cast<T&>(s));`

Comment: Re *which indeed casts away constness* -- that should be "which indeed casts away constness if you tell it to do so." Siler (perhaps unintentionally) told the system to do just that. So it did just that. That's the danger of explicit casts. "I know what I'm doing, so do it."

Comment: You'd simply have to do `return s` if I understand your intent correctly.

Comment: @DavidHammen Ok, improved the phrasing to be more clear.